# How to show user input from dynamic created EditTexts in TextViews into another activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-edittext

In main activity I have button which `onClick` method creates `EditText` every time when user clicks this button. I wanted to pass user input from each `EditText` to `TextView` into another activity. But `TextView` shows user input only from last `EditText`. My code may look strange, because I tried to solve problem on my own. How can I show user input from each created `EditText`? I am new to programming. Thank you in advance.

**Java code**

EditText code

```
int i=1;
int numberOfCreated = 2;
public void buttonCreate(View view){     // button onClick method
    for(i=1;i<numberOfCreated;i++){
        LinearLayout createdEditText1Layout=findViewById(R.id.createdEditText1Layout);
        editText1 = new EditText(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForEditText1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editText1.setLayoutParams(paramsForEditText1);
        editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText1.setHint(R.string.editText1Hint);
        editText1.setTextSize(16);
        createdEditText1Layout.addView(editText1);
    }
}
```

Intent to pass string to second activity

```
    public void openResult() {
    String productName = editText1.getText().toString();
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent2.putExtra("product", productName);
    startActivity(intent2);
}

public  void buttonResultClick(View view){
    openResult();
}
```

Second activity

```
    int i=1;
    int numberOfButtons = 2;
    for(i=1;i<numberOfButtons;i++) {
        LinearLayout layoutForProductName = findViewById(R.id.layoutForProductName);
        TextView productNameTextView = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsForProductNameTextView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        productNameTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsForProductNameTextView);
        productNameTextView.setTextSize(40);
        String productName = getIntent().getStringExtra("product");
        productNameTextView.setText(productName);
        layoutForProductName.addView(productNameTextView);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it's because you're adding only one `String productName`

You can solve this by passing a String Array aka `String[]`

```
    public void openResult() {
    ArrayList<String> productNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int y=0; y < createdEditText1Layout.getChildCount(); y++)
    {
        if((View)layout.getChildAt(y) instanceof TextView){
            String productName = editText1.getText().toString();
            productNames.add(productName);
        }
    }
    
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent2.putStringArrayListExtra("product", productNames);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

And then in the second Activity you would recalled like

```
int i=1;
int numberOfButtons = 2;
for(i=1;i<numberOfButtons;i++) {
    LinearLayout layoutForProductName = findViewById(R.id.layoutForProductName);
    TextView productNameTextView = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsForProductNameTextView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    productNameTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsForProductNameTextView);
    productNameTextView.setTextSize(40);
    String productName = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("product").get(i);
    productNameTextView.setText(productName);
    layoutForProductName.addView(productNameTextView);
}
```

Comment: for(View view: createdEditText1Layout.getChildCount())  shows error **foreach not applicable to type int**

Comment: I did not notice at first, but in the second activity it is also error at `String productName = getIntent().getStringArrayList("product").get(i);` that says **Cannot resolve method getStringArrayList in Intent**

Comment: @Max fixed i missed the `.getExtras()` apologies

Comment: I do not know why, but it is showing input only from last EditText. Anyway, thank you for help.